React Project Deployment to Vercel issue when committing and pushing changes to associated Repository with error ; sh: line 1:vite: command not found
So I am using vercel to deploy my react project and it worked at first
Now to just test that I can update the project through using git like committing and pushing
changes to the repository that it updates the deployed project on vercel, I made a heading change then committed and pushed it but now I get a failed deploy and the errors saying:

sh: line 1: vite: command not found
Error: Command "vite build" exited with 127

Yet vite is included as a devdependency in my package.json
Below is my package.json ;
{
  "name": "game-hub",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^3.2.3",
    "@chakra-ui/theme": "^3.4.6",
    "@chakra-ui/theme-tools": "^2.2.6",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.14.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.9",
    "framer-motion": "^11.15.0",`your text`
    "next-themes": "^0.4.4",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.17.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.10.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.4",
    "eslint": "^9.17.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.16",
    "globals": "^15.14.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.18.2",
    "vite": "^6.0.6",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^5.1.4"
  }
}`

```

I expected to see a succesful update of the change to my applications title changed through me pushing to GitHub but resulted in me being told it failed to deploy and that it cannot find vite yet it is indicated as a dependency in my package.json 

